# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'

Tags: javascript

> The error is in the first line, i have been staring at it forever and cant find the problem.

```
bfs() {
    let result = []
    let queue = []

    queue.push(this.root)

    while(queue.length) {
      let currentNode = queue.shift()

      result.push(currentNode.value)

      if (currentNode.left) {
        queue.push(currentNode.left)
      }
      if (currentNode.right) {
        queue.push(currentNode.right)
      }
    }

    return result
  }
}
```

Comment: `function bfs() {`?

Comment: `} }` ? at the bottom of the code-block?

Comment: Try formatting your code. It makes problems like this really obvious

Comment: Seems pretty clear: you start with `bfs()`, which is a function call, then you have `{` which is the start of a scope _if there was a `;` preceding it_, and now the parser is **very** confused what you're trying to do.

Comment: It was unclear whether you meant to DECLARE a function... or to CALL a function. Putting a function name by itself is calling a function, but putting {} stuff is to declare a function. So, which was it?

Answer (score 1):

```
bf(){

}
```

the above syntax is only valid within the scope of an ES6 class definition or an object literal.

for an object literal

```
const baz ={
     name:"foo",
     bar(){
      //do anything
    }
}
```

for an ES6 class

```
class baz {
   bar(){
     //do something
   }
}
```

any use outside of the above will result in syntax error,

```
bar(); //a function call
```

the above code is used to call or invoke a function.
  To create or define a function, the  syntax below are valid

```
 function bar(){
    //do something
  }
  const baz = ()=>{
    //do something
   }
  const foo = function(){
   //do something
}

 (function(){
  //do something
 })() //immediately invoked function
```